# Parsing datetime in Python..?

Tags: python, datetime, format

I have a system (developed in Python) that accepts **datetime as string in VARIOUS formats** and i have to **parse**  them..Currently datetime string formats are :

```
Fri Sep 25 18:09:49 -0500 2009

2008-06-29T00:42:18.000Z

2011-07-16T21:46:39Z

1294989360
```

Now i want a **generic parser** that can convert any of these datetime formats in appropriate datetime object...

Otherwise, i have to go with parsing them individually. So please also provide method for parsing them individually (if there is no generic parser)..!!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As @TimPietzcker suggested, the dateutil package is the way to go, it handles the first 3 formats correctly and automatically:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("Fri Sep 25 18:09:49 -0500 2009")
datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 25, 18, 9, 49, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
>>> parse("2008-06-29T00:42:18.000Z")
datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 29, 0, 42, 18, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> parse("2011-07-16T21:46:39Z")
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 16, 21, 46, 39, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

The unixtime format it seems to hiccough on, but luckily the standard `datetime.datetime` is up for the task:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float("1294989360"))
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 14, 7, 16)
```

It is rather easy to make a function out of this that handles all 4 formats:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime

def parse_time(s):
    try:
        ret = parse(s)
    except ValueError:
        ret = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s)
    return ret
```

Comment: actually this is what i already did, when @TimPietzcker suggested...u can see that in the comment..!!..but thanx for the awesome reply (and code description)..!!

Comment: To install dateutil: `pip install python-dateutil`. It's like they want you to think it's not a legit package when they don't offer how to install it via `pip`.

Answer (score 15):

You should look into the [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package.

Comment: especially `dateutil.parser.parse()`

Comment: thanx for the answer..!!..but one thing.."dateutil.parser.parse" is parsing first 3 date formats..but it is not able to parse the last date format (which is a long value)..It is showing a "year out of range" Exception... But python inbuilt datetime module is able to parse this long value..why is it so..??