# Concise ASCII Date to Decimal Date

Tags: python, ascii, date-conversion

I wrote a script to read a date in ASCII format of the type 'Tue Nov 18 19:23:17 2014' and convert it to decimal date for plotting. My two lines of code work, but they seem convoluted. I have not been able to find a library function doing this directly, and I think I must be missing something; there should be a way to do this in a concise way. Any suggestion?

```
import time, datetime
from matplotlib import dates
b = time.strptime('Tue Nov 18 19:23:17 2014')
d = dates.date2num(datetime.datetime(b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5]))
print d
#this code results in 735555.807836

#Simplified code incorporating suggestion by Toni_W
from matplotlib import dates
from dateutil.parser import parse
dates.date2num(parse('Tue Nov 18 19:23:17 2014'))
```

Comment: You can use a formula to go directly from `time` to `float`, but it definitely won't be concise.

Comment: How do you deal with time zones? Or is your input assumed to be UTC?

Comment: @Toni_W, thanks: so basically my code gets simplified to one line: dates.date2num(parse('Tue Nov 18 19:23:17 2014'))

Comment: @ghoti I deal only with one particular time, no time zones involoved.

Answer (score 1):

Isnt this what you need?

[Parsing datetime in Python..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516025/parsing-datetime-in-python)

> As @TimPietzcker suggested, the dateutil package is the way to go, it
>   handles the first 3 formats correctly and automatically:
>
> ```
> >>> from dateutil.parser import parse
> >>> parse("Fri Sep 25 18:09:49 -0500 2009")
> datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 25, 18, 9, 49, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
> >>> parse("2008-06-29T00:42:18.000Z")
> datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 29, 0, 42, 18, tzinfo=tzutc())
> >>> parse("2011-07-16T21:46:39Z")
> datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 16, 21, 46, 39, tzinfo=tzutc())
> ```
>
> The unixtime format it seems to hick up on, but luckily the standard
>   `datetime.datetime` is up for the task:
>
> ```
> >>> from datetime import datetime
> >>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float("1294989360"))
> datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 14, 7, 16)
> ```
>
> It is rather easy to make a function out of this that handles all 4
>   formats:
>
> ```
> from dateutil.parser import parse
> from datetime import datetime
>
> def parse_time(s):
>     try:
>         ret = parse(s)
>     except ValueError:
>         ret = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s)
>     return ret
> ```