# How do I get data to read in a format "Days_Hours:Min:Sec.NS" that can be summed, averaged, etc

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

This data is in a array by the thousands.  It has a negative sign where time is 0><4 hrs, and is positive where >4 hrs.  The below format is "Days_hrs:min:sec.nano"  Ex: 68 20:23:16.0 = 68 days, 20 hours, 23 minutes, 16 seconds, 0 ns.  Please see below for an sample of the data set.

```
-0 0:54:38.0
-0 3:59:52.0
0 4:1:17.0
0 5:21:34.0
1 0:10:51.0
68 20:23:16.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing datetime in Python..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516025/parsing-datetime-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another column put:

```
=ABS(--LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))+(--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99))
```

and copy down.  It will create a column of decimal numbers that you can then use in other formulas.

[image]

Then you will want to format that number any way you want, like this:

```
=INT(SUM(B1:B6)) & " " & TEXT(SUM(B1:B6),"hh:mm:ss.0")
```

[image]

Comment: That works great!  Many, many thanks for your help and speedy response!!!

Comment: @mm04 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I have one another question.  The data doesn't sort very well.  Is there a method for sorting this data?  8 23:35:44.0, 89 15:26:18.0, 9 02:22:58.0  Please notice that 89 hours falls between the other 2 points of data in a sort.  Would a sort simply be completed on the decimal format?

Comment: Sort by the number column you are creating and not the text values.  If that does not work please ask a new question.