# can some one help me calculating time difference between two Date Stamps?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, difference

My date formats are like this:
(u'Task', u'2017-01-06T02:23:44.000-0500') .. stage 1
(u'Task', u'2017-01-06T05:27:10.000-0500') .. stage 2
(u'Task', u'2017-01-10T14:42:44.000-0500') ...stage 2

I have to calulcate the time difference between every stage
I am using this (which I know is incorrect :-()

```
    import datetime as dt
    date_format = "yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ss"
    x1= d1.split('T')[0]+' '+(d1.split('T'))[1][:8]
    x2= d2.split('T')[0]+' '+(d2.split('T'))[1][:8]

    d1=('2017-01-06T02:23:44.000-0500')
    d2=('2017-01-19T17:30:21.000-0500')

#some string slicing to get rid of T and the timezone indicator 
    start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(x1, 'yyyy-mm-ddhh:mm:ss')
    end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(x2, 'yyyy-mm-ddhh:mm:ss')

    x = start_dt - end_dt
```

It returns me a format mismatch error

can someone help me find the time spent between stage 1 and stage 2 I have to calculate this recursively

Comment: why `end_dt` have `d1`, it should be `d2` ? isn't it

Comment: Just to be sure - you know that datetime objects can be directly subtracted from each other, right?

Comment: Please help me with that!

Comment: You get a Format mistmatch error because your Format is wrong. Read the documentation: [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) - scroll down to the table and supply the correct `%...` Format parameters into your Format string.

Comment: try `%Y-%m-%d%H-%M-%S` - have no pyfiddle at Hand - and/or read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516025/parsing-datetime-in-python. maybe you should also order you Code a Little - the ordering Looks odd.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, as Patrick wrote, the format string was wrong. You can check how a format string is written [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). Also, the variables `d1` and `d2` were used before they were declared, and subtraction of dates usually works in the way of `difference = older_date - newer_date`. In short:

```
import datetime as dt

date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

d1=('2017-01-06T02:23:44.000-0500')
d2=('2017-01-19T17:30:21.000-0500')

x1 = d1.replace('T', ' ').split('.')[0]
x2 = d2.replace('T', ' ').split('.')[0]

start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(x1, date_format)
end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(x2, date_format)

x = end_dt - start_dt
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
13 days, 15:06:37
```

The splitting for `x1` and `x2` is personal taste, slicing off at indices just asks for the code to be broken during format change or with a different locale.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir,actually what I am working on looks way different,but had to get rid of the problem care stuff! Thanks to Patrick as well

Comment: @SiddharthSonone If you have remaining questions or problems, feel free to ask. If the problem is solved, consider accepting this answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Your format string should be `'%Y-%m-%d%H%M%S'`.
So:

```
start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime((d1.split('T')[0]+''+(d1.split('T'))[1][:8]), '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime((d2.split('T')[0]+''+(d2.split('T'))[1][:8]), '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import datetime as dt

# parses the string in Format 'yyyyMMddHHMMSS'
def parse(s): 
    return dt.datetime.strptime(s,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# removes all T-: from string, leaves to . for split, returns only left part of split                     
def reformat(s): 
    return ''.join([x for x in s if x not in "T-:"]).split('.')[0]

d1=('2017-01-06T02:23:44.000-0500')
d2=('2017-01-19T17:30:21.000-0500')

f1 = reformat(d1)
f2 = reformat(d2)

start = parse(f1)
end   = parse(f2)
delta = end - start

print(d1 + "=>" + f1)
print(d2 + "=>" + f2)
print(delta)
```

Prints:

```
2017-01-06T02:23:44.000-0500=>20170106022344
2017-01-19T17:30:21.000-0500=>20170119173021
13 days, 15:06:37
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fault in the format string :-) thanks for the help